# How do I comment on database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to comment on a database much like I would in Postgres.

```
 COMMENT ON DATABASE postgres
 IS 'default administrative connection database';
```

How would I do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for extended properties.

You can right click on the object, navigate to properties and then extended properties. You can then add or delete values in the Name and Value column.

Typically for things that persist such as user defined functions or stored procedures, all of your comments would be in the code itself. For tables or databases if you needed that extra level of documentation, I'd use extended properties but I would come up with a plan first so it would be consistent across all environments.

[Red gate on documenting databases in SQL Server with extended properties.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-delivery/reading-writing-creating-sql-server-extended-properties/)

The Red Gate article goes into detail about using code (stored procedures and powershell) to maintain and edit those events.

If you would like to use only T-SQL, [SQL Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Metadata/72609/) by [Adam Aspin](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Authors/Articles/Adam_Aspin/335295/) has some good examples.

[Brent Shaub from MSSQLTips on creative approaches using Extended Properties.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2435/creative-uses-for-extended-properties-in-sql-server/)

[MSDN tech notes on Extended Properties.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Is there an example of a way to do this using t-sql?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch I have edited the post to include a T-SQL example.

Answer (score 0):

MD SQL-Server handles commenting on database objects through Extended Properties:

[See detail in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx)